# Android Jetpack Compose Animation on Text not working

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack-compose-ui

I am trying to animate textview with below code but upon testing on emulator, the textview does not animate the way it expected.

Here is my existing code which i am trying on Fragment.

```
           Column(
                modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
                verticalArrangement = Arrangement.Center,
                horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally
            ) {
                AnimatedVisibility(
                    visibleState = textVisibility,
                    enter = fadeIn(animationSpec = tween(3000)) +
                            slideInVertically(
                                animationSpec = tween(3000),
                                initialOffsetY = { (it / 0.5).toInt() }
                            )
                ) {
                    Text(
                        text = "Jetpack Compose",
                        style = MaterialTheme.typography.body1,
                        color = MaterialTheme.colors.textColor
                    )
                }
            }
```

Comment: Checkout developer documentation here https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/animation/quick-guide#animate-text-scale. You should try existing snippets for learning purpose available on GitHub Android.

Comment: Add what is your expectation and what is happening.

Comment: I want my textview to animate fade in with slide in vertically but it does not fade or even slide.